# Is it possible to create a new audio input with NAudio in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, naudio

I want to mix the audio stream of a microphone with the audio output of the system and output it through a new audio input.

Is it possible to create such an audio input with C# and NAudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately this is not possible with NAudio. There are some commercial "virtual audio device/virtual cable" applications that can allow you to achive this